# Javascript -- Why does one document.getElementById() work and not the other?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an interactive invoice and I am very new to programming but so far so good.  I can find most of what I what on the various sites this one being the best.

In HTML I have various tables with 40 or so different input fields such as these:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="idDescLine15" name="fDescLine15" size="50">  </td>
<td><input type="number" id="idQTY15" name="nQTY15" size="5">   </td>
<td><input type="number" id="idPrice15" name="nPrice15" size="5">   </td>
<td class="Checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="idTax15" name="nTax1">  </td>
<td class="TotalCol"><p class="TotalLine" id="idTotalLine15">0.00</p>   </td>
</tr>
```

I have the following function that calculates the row total (quantity * price) for each row.  This above HTML code is for row 15.  All others are setup the same.

```
<script>
function Calculate()
{
    var vSTotalTax = 0;
    for (var i=1;i<16;i++)
    {
        var vbuildQTY = 'idQTY' + i;
        var vbuildPrice = 'idPrice' + i;
        var vbuildTotalLine = 'idTotalLine' + i;
        var vQTY=document.getElementById(vbuildQTY).value;
        var vPrice=document.getElementById(vbuildPrice).value;
        var vTotalLine = (vQTY * vPrice);
        document.getElementById(vbuildTotalLine).innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(vTotalLine * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        vSTotalTax = vSTotalTax + vTotalLine;
    }           
    document.getElementById(idSTotalTax).innerHTML = parseFloat(Math.round(vSTotalTax * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

The first "document.getElementById(vbuildTotalLine)" that is inside the loop works just fine and returns a total for each of the rows.

The second one "document.getElementById(idSTotalTax) does not.  It is set up just the same in the HTML:

```
<tr>
<td><p class="TotalLabel">Sous-total taxable:</p></td>
<td class="TotalCol"><p class="TotalLine" id="idSTotalTax">0.00</p></td>
</tr>
```

When I click the Calculate button I get an error on the page that says the document.getElementById on line 238 is null or not an object.  The only difference between the two is the location in the HTML where it is in a different table.  I tried using one of the 'idTotalLine' field that already worked but I continue with the same error.

Help.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe you want to pass the **string** `"idSTotalTax"`. What happens is that the variable `idSTotalTax` already refers to the element with ID idSTotalTax, so you are passing a DOM element to `getElementById` as argument, which won't work.

Comment: what is "idSTotalTax" in your javascript code ?

Comment: I modified the line (idSTotalTax) to include the single quotes and it works.  Thanks.  Put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `idSTotalTax` already the DOM element. Instead, you mean to use it as a string, passing it to `getElementById`. Wrap it in quotes. Otherwise you are passing the DOM element into `document.getElementById`.

`document.getElementById("idSTotalTax").innerHTML`

-- Thanks to Felix & Pointy for pointing out an earlier issue.

Comment: What's the difference? Please explain your solution, don't just post code.

Comment: If `idSTotalTax` wasn't defined, the code would throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: No. idSTotalTax is just undefined. It won't throw an error. The result of `document.getElementById(undefined)` is `undefined`. If you did `idSTotalTax.SomeProperty`, then you would get an error about `idSTotalTax` not existing.

Comment: If "idSTotalTax" were really `undefined`, it definitely would result in an error. However, in this case it's *not* `undefined`, because it's the "id" of an element and therefore automatically a property of the `window` object.

Comment: I modified the line (idSTotalTax) to include the single quotes and it works.

Comment: You assume that `idSTotalTax` has the value `undefined` because it is not declared anywhere (`var idSTotalTax = ...`). But if that was the case, the code would throw a `ReferenceError`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/gU2yb/. My point is, `idSTotalTax` is defined, but it doesn't have the required value.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you Felix (and Pointy) for pointing that out. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution witch let's you don't bother of the id's.

```
var tr=document.getElementsByTagName('tr'),trl=tr.length,total=0;

while(trl--){
 var td=tr[trl].getElementsByTagName('td'),
 v=td[1].firstChild.value*td[2].firstChild.value;
 td[4].firstChild.textContent=v.toFixed(2);
 total+=v;
}
totalBox=total.toFixed(2);
```

**Note:** by using firstChild there have to be no spaces between the `<td>` and the `<input>`

so you can just write something like that:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="desc[]" size="50"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="qty[]" size="5"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="price[]" size="5"></td>
<td class="Checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="tax[]"></td>
<td class="TotalCol"><p></p></td>
</tr>
```

if you post this form

you will get an array like this:

```
$_POST={
 desc:[
   item1,//item1
   item2 //item2
  ]
 qty:[
   1,//item1
   2//item2
  ]
 price:[
   20,//item1
   25//item2
  ]
 tax:[
   true,//item1
   false//item2
  ]
}
```

and you can add the calculate function on the form itself.

so:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('keyup',calculate,false);
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/gwtmM/

Answer (score 0):

The working call `getElementById(vbuildTotalLine)` looks for the element whose `id` is the *string value of the variable* `vbuildTotalLine`.  In this case, that would be "idTotalLine*N*" for some value of *N* between 1 and 15, inclusive.  You can see in the HTML that there is no element with `id="vbuildTotalLine"`.

The non-working call `getElementById(idSTotalTax)`, similarly, looks for the element whose `id` is the *string value of the variable* `idSTotalTax`, but I see no variable `idSTotalTax` anywhere in your code.  If you want to look up the document whose id is the literal string "idSTotalTax", then you need to pass that value *as* a string, not the name of a variable you don't even declare or assign.  You can do that with code like this:

```
getElementById('idSTotalTax')
```

or perhaps, in keeping with the first part,

```
var vbuildTotalTax = 'idSTotalTax';
...
getElementById(vbuildTotalTax);
```